# Biasing word2vec towards special corpus

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am new to stackoverflow. Please forgive my bad English.

I am using **word2vec** for a school project. I want to work with a domain specific corpus (like Physics Textbook) for creating the word vectors using **Word2Vec**. This standalone does not provide good results due to lesser size of the corpus. This especially hurts as we want to evaluate on words that may very well be outside the vocabulary of the text book.

We want the textbook to encode the domain specific relationships and semantic "nearness". "Quantum" and "Heisenberg" are especially close in this textbook for eg. which may not hold true for background corpus. To handle the generic words (like "any") we need the basic background model(like the one provided by Google on word2vec site).

Is there any way that we can supplant to the background model using our newer corpus. Just training on the corpus etc. doesnot work well.

Are there any attempts to combine vector representations from two corpus- general and specific. I could not find any in my searches.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what do you mean by "weight" and "bias". If you want your new corpus has a stronger impression in the model, perhaps one way to do it is bootstrapping. Or in other words, you train some sentence more than once.
Another solution might be modifying the learning rate `model.alpha = model.alpha * bias`. But that might come with other effects depending on the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about `gensim` since you tagged you question with it. You can load a previously trained model in python using gensim. Then you continue training it. Would it be useful?

```
# load from previous gensim file:
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(fname)
# or from word2vec c format:
# model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/path/vectors.bin', binary=True)

# continue training:
model.train(other_sentences)
model.save(fname)
```

Comment: I tried that already but adding new documents to the corpus behaves the same as if I trained on the whole set of old and new documents together. I want to have more weight (or bias?) towards the new set of documents.